# Query multiple keys while listening to changes - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610264/querying-by-multiple-keys-in-firebase) as a reference, since it is very similar.

If I have a set of defined keys:

```
-Ke1uhoT3gpHR_VsehIv
-Ke8qAECkZC9ygGW3dEJ
-Ke8qMU7OEfUnuXSlhhl
```

and also know that they all do exist under a node (let's say `/items`), how would I query for them, while also listening for changes on those keys (aka not using `myRef.once(value)` but using `myRef.on('value', snapshot => { ... })`

I know this is possible:

```
var keys = [ 
  "-Ke1uhoT3gpHR_VsehIv",
  "-Ke8qAECkZC9ygGW3dEJ",
  "-Ke8qMU7OEfUnuXSlhhl"
];
var promises = keys.map(function(key) {
  return firebase.database().ref("/items/").child(key).once("value");
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
  snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key+": "+snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

but it is a static snapshot. Could it be possible to do the same while listening for changes?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Because the `Promise.all()` in the linked answer was to ensure you can detect when all data has loaded. Since you indicate you want to use regular/`on()` listeners, what is the use-case for waiting for their values?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The keys represent jobs that are showed in a feed. I would like that the jobs within the feed update in real time (lets say that the creator of the job updated the jobs time).

Comment: So that sounds like regular `on()` listeners would work and you don't need `Promise.all()`. The code in your question is a 1:1 copy from my answer you linked. Did you try attaching listeners with `on()` already?

Comment: Yes I attached it. I guess the only way to handle the `on()` listener is that you loop through the keys like so: `for (let i = 0; i < jobKeysArray.length; i++) {
          firebase.database().ref("/jobs/${jobKeysArray[i]}").on('value', snapshot => {
            // handle all incoming data
          })
        }`
Would this be the correct way to do it? Is it done in a single request?
I guess I was expecting a way to store all the promises in an array and also to know once the first read like `Promise.all` was done.

Comment: Since `on()` doesn't return a promise, you can't use `Promise.all()` with it. But you can loop over all keys similar to the code you found and attach a regular `on()` listener. If that is causing problems, post the [code you wrote that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by editing the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is not causing problems but you can definitely see that one object arrives after the other, this means it is not made in one single request?

Comment: Requests are pipelined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have been looking for this. So it seems it doesn't exist, simply because Firebase has an efficient connection it is not necessary to combine 'queries' for the sake of connection performance.

So you would end up setting `on('value', ...)` event listeners for all keys. The code you could write for that could look like this, based on the code fragment given in your question:

```
var keys = [ 
    "-Ke1uhoT3gpHR_VsehIv",
    "-Ke8qAECkZC9ygGW3dEJ",
    "-Ke8qMU7OEfUnuXSlhhl"
];
function itemUpdate(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key+": ", snapshot.val());
}
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/items/");
keys.forEach(function(key) {
    ref.child(key).on("value", itemUpdate);
});
```

Where the only improvements would be to define the callback function or else you would create as many callback functions as you have keys to listen on and second to place the ref in a var.

Comment: What if the number of keys you were trying to listen to was large? Like, let's say you were trying to listen to all members of a group, and the group could have 100s of users. Would you suggest in this case making a key for the group and listening to the group key instead?

Comment: I don't think 100s of listeners is that much for the Firebase connection to handle. I haven't worked with group keys, but you can try if that works for you. It's quite hard though to process changes when setting a listener on a high level with the purpose of monitoring changes on a deeper level. IMO it's better to set listeners on the exact child elements instead.