# How to send multiple queries to firebase database at once in android without putting in a loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query the database to check through multiple unrelated keys to check a parameter and compile a list that fits my conditions.

I already have a list which was created with a previous query to another node of the database.  Which returned a list of keys which i want to check.

Now i want to iterated through this list and query them to see if they fit my conditions.

I have tried downloading whole node and checking client side but this would become very slow if the node grows and download a lot of unnecessary data.

I have tried putting a loop around my query and sending multiple queries within, on the keys in my list. This worked but becomes increasingly complicated as i try to go back to the beginning with different conditions if my original conditions were not met.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nextUp.size(); i++) {
    Query query = myRef.child(nextUp.get(i).toString());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean v = false;

            for (DataSnapshot likesSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (uid.equals(likesSnapshot.getKey())) {
                    v = true;
                } else {
                }

                //b if for second pass with different conditions
                if (b) {
                    if (!v) {
                        complieList(dataSnapshot.getKey(), b);
                    }

                    if (!b) {
                        complieList(dataSnapshot.getKey(), b);
                    }
                }

            }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

By the time my code goes back to the beginning all the queries have not yet complete.  So i need to wait for all to finish to continue.  But as this requires waiting for the results for many queries i cannot simply put it in the onDataChange.  I have seen that a JavaScript promise can send multiple queries at once in a pipeline and receive the result for all of them.  Is there a way to do this in Java.

**Update**

Here is a link to what i want to do but it is for javascript
[Querying By Multiple Keys in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610264/querying-by-multiple-keys-in-firebase?rq=1)

Comment: Please add your database structure and provide us an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using transaction?

Transaction is used to composite serveral db request and request one time.

It is also used to prevent data change during db request.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler?hl=ko

by the way, realtime db doesn’t support complicate query

you can use only orderbychild.. etc

But you can store data separately when data is saved.

Comment: My understanding is a transaction will download the whole node.  This would be much more data than i need. I just want to read the children with certain keys.